# Intent.setData vs Intent.putExtra

Tags: java, android, api, android-intent

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCalendar/article.html

I understand what putExtra does

but I fail to understand what setData() means?

Android Docs, wasn't much helpful:

`Set the data this intent is operating on.`

what does this mean for the constant

`intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);` ?

There doesn't seem to be any affect when I comment out this line.

Comment: Have you looked into [CalendarContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html) to get a better idea?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`setData()` is used to point to the **location** of a data object (like a file for example), while `putExtra()` adds **simple data types** (such as an SMS text string for example).

Here are two examples to clarify:

`setData()` used here to set the location of a file that you want to share.

```
File fileToShare = new File("/sdcard/somefile.dat");
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setData(Uri.fromFile(fileToShare));
startActivity(i);
```

`putExtra()` is used here to set the text content that you want to share.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String textBodyString = "some text";
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textBodyString);
i.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
```

For more information I suggest some readings about [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) and the `setData()`, `setType()` and `setDataAndType()`

Comment: I really can say its a very bad naming. I don't why can't they just name it like `setUri`. And for the setExtras just name it like, `setData` instead? I don't know, I still don't get the entire picture. I am just hoping the name would communicate better.

Comment: A tiny correction. "string" should be "String" in the second example.

Answer (score 5):

setData() is used for the Android System to find an application component that matches the data attribute in implicit intent.

---

putExtra() is mainly used to pass some information to the selected application component,by the Android system.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `.putExtra` is to transfer a string or something. like Aramex :P

while `.setData` is to set the intent's data type.

see in the intent it's `Intent.ACTION_INSERT`. So it's waiting for something to be inserted. That's why you set the data. `.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);` You inserted the calendar events.

Comment: so how come it works even if I remove this line? `.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);` ?

Comment: ` So it's waiting for something to be inserted.` who is inserting anything?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a good answer here: https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%201/21_c_understanding_activities_and_intents.html

Use the intent data field (Intent.setData):
- When you only have one piece of information you need to send to the started activity.
- When that information is a data location that can be represented by a URI.

Use the intent extras (Intent.putExtra):
- If you want to pass more than one piece of information to the started activity.
- If any of the information you want to pass is not expressible by a URI.

Intent data and extras are not exclusive; you can use data for a URI and extras for any additional information the started activity needs to process the data in that URI.