# Difference between putExtra() and setData()

Tags: android, android-intent

What is the difference between putExtra() and setData()? I have read the android docs but it is of not much help.
Also there is a previous question [Intent.setData vs Intent.putExtra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794504/intent-setdata-vs-intent-putextra)  but it is still not clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setData(android.net.Uri) and this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 8):

**setData()**

Set the data this intent is operating on. This method automatically clears any type that was previously set by setType(String) or setTypeAndNormalize(String).

*Note*: scheme matching in the Android framework is case-sensitive, unlike the formal RFC. As a result, you should always write your Uri with a lower case scheme, or use normalizeScheme() or setDataAndNormalize(Uri) to ensure that the scheme is converted to lower case.

*Parameters*

> data: The Uri of the data this intent is now targeting.

Intents are used to signal to the Android system that a certain event has occurred. Intents often describes the action which should be performed and provide data on which such an action should be done. For example your application can start via an intent a browser component for a certain URL. This is demonstrated by the following example.

```
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
```

But how does the Android system identify the components which can react to a certain intent?

For this the concept of an intent filter is used. An intent filter specifies the types of intents to which that an activity , service, or broadcast receiver can respond to. It declares therefore the capabilities of a component.

Android components register intent filters either statically in the AndroidManifest.xml or in case of a broadcast receiver also dynamically via code. An intent filter is defined by its category, action and data filters. It can also contain additional metadata.

If an intent is send to the Android system, the Android platform runs, using the data included in the Intent object, an receiver determination. In this it determines the components which are registered for the data of the intent. If several components have registered for the same intent filter the user can decide which component should be started.

**putExtra()**

Add extended data to the intent.

*Parameters*:

> name:  The name of the extra data.
>
> value: The String array data value.

Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls into a single statement.

Comment: could you please explain in more detail what 'set the data this intent is operating on' means??

Comment: thanks.. this cleared things somewhat.. but suppose i want to launch an explicit intent, then what to set in setData?? In that case can I use putextra to provide the uri?

Answer (score 5):

`putExtra` allows you to add primitive (or parcelable) key-value pairs. `setData` is limited to passing an `Uri`. `setData` is conventionally used for the case of requesting data from another source, such as in startActivityForResult.

Comment: but an uri can be sent through putextra also.

Comment: Yes, but get/setData don't require a 'key' - put/getExtra do. set/getData is really just a shorthand for not having to come up with this key that every app knows about.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the source:

```
/**
 * Set the data this intent is operating on.  This method automatically
 * clears any type that was previously set by {@link #setType} or
 * {@link #setTypeAndNormalize}.
 *
 * <p><em>Note: scheme matching in the Android framework is
 * case-sensitive, unlike the formal RFC. As a result,
 * you should always write your Uri with a lower case scheme,
 * or use {@link Uri#normalizeScheme} or
 * {@link #setDataAndNormalize}
 * to ensure that the scheme is converted to lower case.</em>
 *
 * @param data The Uri of the data this intent is now targeting.
 *
 * @return Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls
 * into a single statement.
 *
 * @see #getData
 * @see #setDataAndNormalize
 * @see android.net.Uri#normalizeScheme()
 */
public Intent setData(Uri data) {
    mData = data;  // private Uri mData
    mType = null;  // private String mType;
    return this;
}

/**
 * Add extended data to the intent.  The name must include a package
 * prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names
 * like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".
 *
 * @param name The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
 * @param value The String data value.
 *
 * @return Returns the same Intent object, for chaining multiple calls
 * into a single statement.
 *
 * @see #putExtras
 * @see #removeExtra
 * @see #getStringExtra(String)
 */
public Intent putExtra(String name, String value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putString(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setData()` is to pass data on which, action has to be taken; while `putExtra()` is to send extra information about the action.

For example, if one is starting an activity to perform `ACTION_CALL`, then he has to set the number to call in `setData()`. And if he wants to pass any other extra information, then he should use `putExtra()`.

Comment: Directly copied from Skillgun, but short and pretty precise: http://skillgun.com/question/449/android/basics/what-is-the-importance-of-putextra-method-in-android-how-is-it-different-from-setdata-any-way-both-are-passing-data-only-then-what-is-the-difference