# Intent - setData vs Extras

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I don't quite understand the real purpose of Data field for intents.

I have seen some examples like the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
        startActivity(intent);
```

So from the documentation it seems like Data just gives you the URI, basically where the data is located.

Can't everything just be done using `putExtra` and just have the `Activity` get the extra.

For the example above, you could just put the telephone number in the extra and have the activity get the extra and then dial. When would you use `setData` vs `putExtra`?

Comment: setData() is used to point to the location of a data object (like a file for example), while putExtra() adds simple data types Ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794504/intent-setdata-vs-intent-putextra#answer-21363437

Comment: @Sachin but it doesn't seem like that's always the case since in my example it's a String. Would you only use setData if you were unable to putExtra. since putExtra can accept more complex data types as long as it's Parcelable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can't everything just be done using putExtra and just have the Activity get the extra.

Extras do not control routing of `Intents`. The action string, data (`Uri`), MIME type, and categories do. Extras are merely payload.

In this case, `ACTION_CALL` of a `tel:` `Uri` might be handled differently than `ACTION_CALL` of a `sip:` `Uri`. Only SIP-compatible VOIP clients could handle the latter. Hence, the activities for telephony-related apps can include details in their `<intent-filter>` elements to watch for only those `Uri` schemes that they can handle (among other possible constraints).

Comment: so a key advantage of setData is that the system is able to determine the MIME type and help it route instead of having different intents for 'sip:' and 'tel:' calls?

Comment: @Alan: Um, I would not phrase it that way. There is only one `Uri` in an `Intent`, so by definition there would be "different intents for 'sip:' and 'tel:' calls". Also, a `tel:` `Uri` does not have a MIME type. An `<intent-filter>` for an activity, etc. can filter on whatever is needed. In this case, activities with `ACTION_CALL` in their `<intent-filter>` elements might include the scheme as part of that filter.

Answer (score 0):

putExtra actually adds the data in the intent. It gets serialized when it is sent to another activity where it gets deserialized. These are expensive operations that could affect the performance. There is also a limit on how much data can be sent like this. If you have a big piece of data (several MBs) then it is better to use setData rather than putExtra.

Comment: that makes sense, but does that means you can only use setData if the data is stored on the device (like a PDF in the file system) or a web link?

Comment: You could also put the data in memory cache and pass the key to the cache as the intent data.